# PHP/HTML Query string being removed from url link

Tags: php, html, redirect, tracking

Im trying to pass a link with contains a full url;

```
http://xxx.co.uk/trackit.php?page=http://xxx.co.uk/game?p=buildings&menu
```

As you can see in the link above, first it goes to a script called trackit, does some tracking then redirects to the actual page i want, however in this case the '&menu' is being removed, i think i understand why, but have been unable to fix it.

```
$next_page = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['page']);
header("Location: $next_page");
```

Any advise would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Put a '\' before the '&' symbol and check and let me know .

Comment: Need to urlencode the URL in the page variable before displaying the link

Comment: [urlencode()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your `menu` and `p` parameter values. This might help in your case. For eg: Review the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//before display your url
$page = urlencode('http://xxx.co.uk/game?p=buildings&menu');
$url = 'http://xxx.co.uk/trackit.php?page=' . $page;

echo $url;
// displays
// http://xxx.co.uk/trackit.php?page=http%3A%2F%2Fxxx.co.uk%2Fgame%3Fp%3Dbuildings%26menu


//when you receive it on the get
$next_page = urldecode($_GET['page']);
header("Location: $next_page");
```